# Select with group by and max date

Tags: sql-server

this probably is a duplicate question but I can't seem to figure out how to implement the previous suggestions.

my data looks like this for what matters:

```
drawing    method       Location        thk_date
314C0010   UT       05.01       2016-05-24 
314C0010   UT       05.01       2011-10-26 
314C0010   UT       06.01       2016-05-24 
314C0010   UT       07.01       2016-05-24
```

When my select executes for location 05.01 I only want the row with the latest thk_Date

Here is my statement which just gets all the records.

```
SELECT Distinct
   t.[Id]
  ,t.[SurveyNumber]
  ,t.[TPLATFORM]
  ,t.[DRAWING]
  ,r.[Desc]
  ,t.[METHOD]
  ,t.[LOCATION]
  ,t.[THK_DATE]
  ,t.[THICK]
  ,t.[MEAS_THK]
  ,t.[COMMENTS]
  ,t.[EXCLUDE]
  ,t.[PAINT]
  ,t.[CF1]
  ,t.[CF2]
  ,t.[CF3]
  ,t.[NF1]
  ,t.[NF2]
  ,t.[Year]
  ,t.[Completed]
  ,t.Created
  ,t.CreatedBy
  ,t.ModifiedBy
  ,t.Modified
  ,YEAR(THK_DATE)
  ,t.Inservice

FROM Thk t
left JOIN ref r ON r.[DRAWING] = t.[DRAWING]
left JOIN eng e ON e.[DRAWING] = t.[DRAWING]

WHERE t.SurveyNumber = @SurveyNumber 
AND t.[Year] = @Year

ORDER BY t.DRAWING, t.Method, t.[LOCATION], THK_DATE desc
```

How do I get only the rows with the max(thk_date)? I have tried to group and select top 1 but only get one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this.

Since you haven't given other tables' structure, here is an example.

```
declare @Drawings as 
Table(drawing varchar(100), 
      method varchar(2), 
      Location varchar(10),
      thk_date DateTime)

INSERT INTO @Drawings
VALUES
('314C0010', 'UT','05.01','2016-05-24'), 
('314C0010', 'UT','05.01','2011-10-26'), 
('314C0010', 'UT','06.01','2016-05-24'), 
('314C0010', 'UT','07.01','2016-05-24') 


;WITH CTE AS
(
select row_number() over(partition by Location order by thk_date desc) as rn,*
from @Drawings
)

select * from CTE where rn=1
```

[Fiddle here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1045284)

Comment: ;WITH CTE AS
(
select row_number() over(partition by drawing, location order by thk_date desc) as rn,*
from #Temp
)